# Move elements within MongoDB document

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongodb-nodejs-driver

## Background:

A customer is an object that has a name field.

A line is an object that has the following fields:

- `inLine` - an array of customers
- `currentCustomer` - a customer
- `processed` - an array of customers

The collection 'line' contains documents that are line objects.

---

## Problem:

I'm trying to implement a procedure which would do the following:

1. Push `currentCustomer` to `processed`
2. Set `currentCustomer` to the 1st element in `inLine`
3. Pop the 1st element of `inLine`

Since the new value of a field depends on the previous value of another, atomicity is important here.

## What I tried so far:

### Naive approach

```js
db.collection('line').findOneAndUpdate({
    _id: new ObjectId(lineId),
}, {
    $set: {
        currentCustomer: '$inLine.0',
    },
    $pop: {
        inLine: -1,
    },
    $push: {
        processed: '$currentCustomer',
    },
});
```

However, `currentCustomer` is set to a string which is literally "$inLine.0" and `processed` has a string which is literally "$currentCustomer".

### Aggregation approach

```js
db.collection('line').findOneAndUpdate({
    _id: new ObjectId(lineId),
}, [{
    $set: {
        currentCustomer: '$inLine.0',
    },
    $pop: {
        inLine: -1,
    },
    $push: {
        processed: '$currentCustomer',
    },
}]);
```

However, I got the following error:

> MongoError: A pipeline stage specification object must contain exactly one field.

### Multi-stage aggregation approach

```js
db.collection('line').findOneAndUpdate({
    _id: new ObjectId(lineId),
}, [{
    $set: {
        currentCustomer: '$inLine.0',
    },
}, {
    $pop: {
        inLine: -1,
    },
}, {
    $push: {
        processed: '$currentCustomer',
    },
}]);
```

However, `$pop` and `$push` are Unrecognized pipeline stage names.

I tried making it using only `$set` stages, but it ended up very ugly and I still couldn't get it to work.

Comment: [Update MongoDB field using value of another field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3974985/update-mongodb-field-using-value-of-another-field)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on [turivishal's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64861846/6517320), it was solved like so:

```js
db.collection('line').findOneAndUpdate({
    _id: new ObjectId(lineId),
}, [{
    $set: {
        // currentCustomer = inLine.length === 0 ? null : inLine[0]
        currentCustomer: {
            $cond: [
                { $eq: [{ $size: '$inLine' }, 0] },
                null,
                { $first: '$inLine' },
            ],
        },
        // inLine = inLine.slice(1)
        inLine: {
            $cond: [
                { $eq: [{ $size: '$inLine' }, 0] },
                [],
                { $slice: ['$inLine', 1, { $size: '$inLine' }] },
            ],
        },
        // if currentCustomer !== null then processed.push(currentCustomer)
        processed: {
            $cond: [
                {
                    $eq: ['$currentCustomer', null],
                },
                '$processed',
                {
                    $concatArrays: [
                        '$processed', ['$currentCustomer'],
                    ],
                }
            ],
        },
    },
}]);
```

Comment: Worth noting: This currently doesn't work on MongoDB M0 Sandbox (which is the free one) because it runs version 4.2, but [`$first` is new in 4.4](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64937528/6517320).

Answer (score 1):

I don't think its possible with simple update using `$push or $pop`.

As per your experiment, the aggregation can not support direct `$push, $pop` stage in root level, so I have corrected your query,

- `currentCustomer` check condition if size of `inLine` is 0 then return null otherwise get first element from `inLine` array using [$arrayElemAt](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayElemAt/index.html),
- `inLine` check condition if size of `inLine` is 0 then return [] otherwise remove first element from `inLine` array using [$slice](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/slice/) and [$size](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/size/index.html)
- `processed` concat both arrays using [$concatArrays](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/concatArrays/index.html), [$ifNull](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/ifNull/index.html) to check if field is null then return blank array, check condition if `currentCustomer` null then return [] otherwise return `currentCustomer`

```
db.collection('line').findOneAndUpdate(
  { _id: new ObjectId(lineId), }, 
  [{
    $set: {
      currentCustomer: {
        $cond: [
          { $eq: [{ $size: "$inLine" }, 0] },
          null,
          { $arrayElemAt: ["$inLine", 0] }
        ]
      },
      inLine: {
        $cond: [
          { $eq: [{ $size: "$inLine" }, 0] },
          [],
          { $slice: ["$inLine", 1, { $size: "$inLine" }] }
        ]
      },
      processed: {
        $concatArrays: [
          { $ifNull: ["$processed", []] },
          {
            $cond: [
              { $eq: ["$currentCustomer", null] },
              [],
              ["$currentCustomer"]
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }]
);
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/407X4ziOnLE)

Comment: If `currentCustomer` is null, this pushes null in to `processed`.

Comment: If `inLine` is empty then it errors with "Third argument of $slice must be positive: 0"

Comment: If `inLine` is empty, it should remain empty.

Comment: `[]` is empty array.

Comment: This still pushes `null` in to `processed` if `currentCustomer` is null. Did you mean to instead wrap `$currentCustomer` in `$ifNull`?

Comment: This query playground indeed solves the issue with `inLine`, but `processed` still gets `null` if `currentCustomer` is `null`.

Comment: I have clear the comments and updated latest answer, it will helpful for someone as well.