# Unrecognized expression '$first'

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I need to extract the first item from an array and add it to its own object, so I found $first the does exactly that https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/first-array-element/#example
However, I was getting the error `Unrecognized expression '$first'` and thought it was my query that wasn't working, so I cloned the exact example they have in their docs, but it gives me the same error.

```
db.runninglog.insertMany([
 { "_id" : 1, "team" : "Anteater", log: [ { run: 1, distance: 8 }, { run2: 2, distance: 7.5 }, { run: 3, distance: 9.2 } ] },
 { "_id" : 2, "team" : "Bears", log: [ { run: 1, distance: 18 }, { run2: 2, distance: 17 }, { run: 3, distance: 16 } ] },
 { "_id" : 3, "team" : "Cobras", log: [ { run: 1, distance: 2 } ] }
])

db.runninglog.aggregate([
 { $addFields: { firstrun: { $first: "$log" }, lastrun: { $last: "$log" } } }
])
```

Expected: What the doc is expecting.
Received: `Unrecognized expression '$first'`

**Edit**

I found out another way to do the same thing with  `{ $addFields: { firstrun: { $arrayElemAt: [ "$log", 0 ] } } }` but still I'm curious about the above

Comment: It seems works ok [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/ISKVEkWen6m)

Comment: which version of mongodb are you using ? `$addFields' added from version 3.4

Comment: is running the command in Atlas, and seems a bug @eshirvana. Not sure about compass

Comment: MongoDB 4.2.10 Enterprise. Compass version 1.23.0 (but it fails on the code and on the command line as well).

Comment: Should I report that as a bug instead?

Comment: @Shadoweb runs fine here in 4.2 Mongo Shell. You can fire a ticket in JIRA, it won't hurt anyone.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From the [Documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/first-array-element/) : new in version 4.4

Be careful, the one you try to use is the $first array element operator, different from the [$first aggregation accumulator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/first/) available in $group stage.

Comment: yes... the doc of 4.4 version. But not exists in 4.2, which is the version used by @Shadoweb