# How to update values in string array in all documents? - MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I have in my collection this structure:

```
{
    _id: ObjectId('...'),
    images: [
        "images/key1",
        "images/key2",
        "images/key3",
        "images/key4"
    ],
    .... ,
    ....
}
```

So, I want to update all documents to:

```
{
    _id: ObjectId('...'),
    images: [
        "key1",
        "key2",
        "key3",
        "key4"
    ],
    .... ,
    ....
}
```

Replacing in all values 'images/' with ''. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could done it with update aggregation like this
first match the doc and then in project use map and them split and choose last element

```
db.collection.update({},
[
  {
    $addFields: {
      images: {
        $map: {
          input: "$images",
          as: "i",
          in: {
            $last: {
              $split: [
                "$$i",
                "images/"
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
],{multi:true})
```

https://mongoplayground.net/p/6fDBAlpKDBj

or use this

```
db.collection.update({},
[
  {
    $addFields: {
      images: {
        $map: {
          input: "$images",
          as: "i",
          in: {
            $arrayElemAt: [
              {
                $split: [
                  "$$i",
                  "images/"
                ]
              },
              1
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
],{multi:true})
```

replace $last with $arrayelementAt
https://mongoplayground.net/p/ecHMquZGazy

Comment: I get an error that say: Unrecognized expression '$last'. Do you know what is happening?

Comment: I split item of images and it will convert to array , and $last means put last element of array

Comment: did you see my playground ?

Comment: Yes, it worked!. but when i use it in my db i get that error.

Comment: could you provide your code ?

Comment: Sure.
`
db.residences.update({},
[
  {
    $project: {
      images: {
        $map: {
          input: "$images",
          as: "i",
          in: {
            $last: {
              $split: [
                "$$i",
                "images/"
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
`

Comment: does `db.residences,find({})` return value to you ?

Comment: I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64935182/unrecognized-expression-first/64937528), My current version is 4.2.8, maybe i've to update.

Comment: Yes!, it returns all documents.

Comment: my answer has been updated

Comment: It's very weird, [see](https://mongoplayground.net/p/M6fiZM66BGl). In the playground both solutions only update the first element and the second solution in my db doesn't update nothing, I don't get errors but no row is updated.

Comment: lookat this https://mongoplayground.net/p/yna2bczU581
add {multi:true} as new update argument

Comment: my answer has been updated

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238838/discussion-between-juanda237-and-mohammad-naimi).